# New iPhone developer error

Tags: ios, iphone

Am creating a single view application.

Then on storyboard, i drag a label into the middle of the page. then set a constraint to be in middle on any device

when i run on iPhone retina 4 inch it works fine, when i run on iPhone retina 3.5 inch i get the following error

```
2014-09-03 11:02:35.136 Testing[3879:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.       
Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) 
find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If 
you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to   
the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8e9b760 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x8e876a0]-(253)-[UILabel:0x8e99cc0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8e9b790 V:[UILabel:0x8e99cc0]-(274)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x8e9b010]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x8e9b410 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x8e876a0(20)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x8e98f10 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x8e876a0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x8e99ae0 )>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x8e97de0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x8e9b010(0)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x8e9b7c0 _UILayoutGuide:0x8e9b010.bottom == UIView:0x8e99ae0.bottom>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x8e9e2e0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0x8e99ae0(480)]>"
```

)

do note, the error of constraint is on the top constraint. probably because of the bar. any helps?

Comment: so any help? i am newbie and thought someone can quickly help me in an error like this

Answer (score 0):

Ok , solved by myself.

Just need to apple retina inch 3.5 form factor, not retina inch 4.0 form factor.